# Can't import class and module on Python progrram

Tags: python

I do not program on Python, so I don't know what the problem is.
I just can't start the program from the command line, this is displayed:

[image]

Here is code `__init__.py`

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

from pynfb.experiment import Experiment
from pynfb.io.xml_ import xml_file_to_params
from pynfb.settings_widget.general import GeneralSettingsWidget
from pynfb.settings_widget.inlet import InletSettingsWidget
from pynfb.settings_widget.protocol_sequence import ProtocolSequenceSettingsWidget
from pynfb.settings_widget.protocols import ProtocolsSettingsWidget, FileSelectorLine
from pynfb.settings_widget.signals import SignalsSettingsWidget
from pynfb.settings_widget.composite_signals import CompositeSignalsSettingsWidget
from pynfb.settings_widget.protocols_group import ProtocolGroupsSettingsWidget

static_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/static')
 
class SettingsWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
```

Comment: You didn't install PyQt4

Answer (score 3):

You need to install PyQt4 first: `https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4`.

Download the correct file corresponding to the version of your python, e.g. `PyQt4‑4.11.4‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` then install by using pip (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

```
pip install PyQt4-4.11.4-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: I did all this, but I get the same error as in my original question

https://ibb.co/cDqsMLx

Comment: Are you using conda? If so you may need to install as instructed here https://github.com/nikolaims/nfb/tree/pyqt4-stable

Comment: If i use instruction on this link https://github.com/nikolaims/nfb/tree/pyqt4-stable
Then I just do not have these files in the folder Scripts

If on this https://github.com/nikolaims/nfb
Then it writes to me that all the packages are installed, but the program still does not start bcz i dont have module pyqt4

Comment: How do u think maybe i should try delete pyqt5 and install pyqt4? I have pyqt5 yes?
https://ibb.co/z7V6pqw

Comment: Hmm as seen from before you did successfully install PyQt4 but for some reason your Python cannot find it, so removing `pyqt5` is not likely going to help.

Comment: Also this `python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"`

Comment: Ok this is really strange since it shows that you have already installed PyQt4 in the right location.(`C:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages`) and also Python do find the right folder (as in `sys.path`) so I believe either you have some file name `PyQt4.py` or you have other problem not `ModuleNotFound` error anymore. Can you print output of this `python -c "import PyQt4"`?

Comment: Damn... This is tricky, ok please try this final hack. Add this line `sys.path.append('c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages')` before your `from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore` then try again

Comment: Your stacktrace show line 4 in `__init__.py` but your code show line 12, are you sure its the same file? Anyway for simplicity, try switching line 10 and 11 in your `main.py`

Comment: Yes i really did mistake on previous comment, but now i did right
Still see this
https://ibb.co/VQwzvtm
https://ibb.co/XZqwPFQ

Comment: sorry mate, your problem is something i have never encountered before. My best bet would be creating a virtualenv (see https://programwithus.com/learn-to-code/Pip-and-virtualenv-on-Windows/) and reinstall all library in that env and try again